# libevのev_asyncとは何に使用するものですか？

Tags: linux, socket

ドキュメントを読んでもいまいち理解できませんでした。
http://linux.die.net/man/3/ev

詳しい方がいましたら教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 1):

libevのドキュメントでしたら [本家のREADME](http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/libev/ev.pod) を参照するのが良いと思います。

**`ev_async`** は、マルチスレッド環境でイペントループに対して安全にイベントを通知する仕組みです。例えば、あるスレッドが **`ev_run()`** しているイベントループに対して、別のスレッドからループの終了を通知したいといった目的で利用されます。

以下に **`ev_async`** を用いて、別スレッドからイベントループを終了させるサンプルのコードを載せておきます。（※ エラー処理など省略しています）

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <ev.h>

struct ev_loop *loop;
struct ev_async shutdown_w;

static void *
thread_main (void *arg) {
    sleep(3);
    fprintf(stderr, "ev_async_send\n");
    ev_async_send(loop, &shutdown_w); // thread safe
    return NULL;
}

static void
on_shutdown (struct ev_loop *loop, struct ev_async *w, int revents) {
    fprintf(stderr, "on_shutdown\n");
    ev_break(loop, EVBREAK_ALL);
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t id;

    loop = ev_default_loop(0);

    ev_async_init(&shutdown_w, on_shutdown);
    ev_async_start(loop, &shutdown_w);

    pthread_create(&id, NULL, thread_main, NULL);

    fprintf(stderr, "ev_run: start\n");
    ev_run(loop, 0);
    fprintf(stderr, "ev_run: stop\n");

    return 0;
}
```